# Joomla chat for particular user only

Tags: php, joomla

I want a joomla chat component / module by which a visitor can chat with a particular registered user only if that user is online. I found many chat extensions, but they were not working for a particular user. I only find chat room.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with "BoWoB Chat" plugin: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/chat-hosted/12803

Using the feature "Friend-only chat".

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a free extension for this which I tested about a year ago. It was average with a few bugs but they developers have constantly updated it since then and it's now commercial:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/chat/19758

You may also want to take a look at the following:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/chat/17600

Both are based on the Facebook Chat style, however both are also commercial. If you're looking for a non-commercial solution, then [FreiChat](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/chat/13106) may suit your needs. I have never tested it but the ratings and reviews are good.